# ClassNotFoundException org.kie.api.conf.KieBaseOption

Tags: java, maven, drools

Obviously the class KieBaseOption can't be found because I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kie.api.conf.KieBaseOption
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1955)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl$ReflectionInstantiator.newInstance(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:198)
    at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl$ReflectionInstantiator.call(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:193)
    at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl.get(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory.loadServiceFactory(KnowledgeBaseFactory.java:164)
    at org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory.getKnowledgeBaseFactoryService(KnowledgeBaseFactory.java:157)
    at org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBaseFactory.java:63)
    at ...Validierer.runRules(Validierer.java:28)
...
```

Which maven module might I be missing?
(Also, is drools-bom really necessary?)

I am migrating from an old 5.x version to 7.50.
Using the following maven dependencies.

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.50.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.50.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.50.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-bom -->
´       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.50.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be missing any, `KieBaseOption` is a part of KIE-API. I've just tested it on an empty project with nothing but the exact same KIE-API dependency as you have and it worked fine, so no, you don't need to add a `drools` dependency for KIE-API to work.

Try reimporting maven dependencies in your IDE and rebuilding the project completely.